# Exercise about probability with Venn diagram

Tags: probability

I have a statement that says:

> In one class there are 40 students. 50% of them play soccer, 37.5%
>   play basketball, and 5 students play both. What is the probability,
>   that when selecting a student at random, do not play anything?

I tried this:

$0.5 + 0.375 = 0.875$, I do not add the 5 students($0.125$), since these are contained within those who play soccer and basketball.

Ok, then the students that not play anything are: $1 - 0.875 = 0.125$, but the correct answer should be $0.25$, so what is my error ?

Comment: "these are contained within those who play soccer and basketball."  Yes, and so you have counted them twice.

Comment: You actually need to subtract the $.125$ as you have added those $5$ in twice.

Comment: $\frac {5}{40} = \frac 18 = 12.5\%$ play both, so we have those playing a sport (or both) equal to $0.5+ 0.375 - .125 = 0.75$.  So the probability of randomly selecting a student who doesn't play any sport is therefore $1-0.75 = 0.25$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $P(S \cup B) = P(S) + P(B) - P(S \cap B).$ Do not ignore the intersection.

Then $P(\text{Neither}) = P[(S \cup B)^c] = 1 - P(S \cup B).$

If there are only these two sports at the school, playing neither S nor B is the same as not playing any sport.

It is a good idea to make a Venn diagram. Can you see that $(S \cup B)^c =
S^c \cap B^c?$

Another good way to approach such a problem is to make a table:

```
                          Soccer
                     YES          NO        Total
           --------------------------------------                    
           YES         5          10          15
Basketball
           NO         15          10          25
           --------------------------------------
           Total      20          20          40
```

Comment: Nice, then the 10 is the 25% , because is intersection of two `no`

Comment: Right. This kind of 'two-by-two' table is often clearer than a Venn diagram. It explicitly displays the four counts, and also the 'marginal' totals.

Comment: Could you give me your mail? To ask questions of mathematics from time to time? If it's not too much trouble, please (I'm still in high school)

Comment: I'm teaching a graduate course this quarter and so have limited time to spend on this site. Even so, I try to visit almost every day. And there are others here to help you when I can't. Wishing you success in your statistics/probability course. Hope to see other questions from you. Just be sure to continue showing what you have tried, explain what you have studied recently, etc., so we will be able to give appropriate help.